# How get coordinates from polygons inside a Layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a `LayerGroup`

```
var mapLayer = new L.layerGroup();
```

This is how I add several polygons to this `LayerGroup`:

```
var buffered = turf.buffer(polyline, path_alarmweight, 'meters');
bufferedPolygon = L.geoJson(buffered, bufferedOptions).addTo(mapLayer);`
```

How can I get the coordinates from a single or several polygons which I added to the `mapLayer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to get all layers from `LayerGroup`, use `getLayers()` function, in [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayers). You will get layers in LayerGroup:

```
var arrayOfLayers = mapLayer.getLayers();
```

Then you can iterate over `arrayOfLayers` and for every layer you can get coordinates of polygon with `getLatLngs()` function. See the [reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#multipolygon-getlatlngs):

```
for(var i=0; i < arrayOfLayers.length; i++) {
// first get array of coordinates
var arrayOfPoints = arrayOfLayers[i].getLatLngs();

    //then iterate over coordinates
    for(var j=0; j < arrayOfPoints.length; j++) {
        console.log(arrayOfPoints[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but now i get an TypeError:
TypeError: arrayOfLayers[i].getLatLngs is not a function

Comment: ok. i get it. I just called "var arrayOfLayers = mapLayer.getLayers();" one more time.  Thanks a lot for your help.